# Invalid Column after Renaming

Tags: sql, database, hana

I have a nested SQL statement. In the inner SQL statement I rename a column like this: `b."MANDT" b_MANDT`. In the outer statement I try something similar: `a."b_MANDT" a_b_MANDT`.

But I'm getting the error message that this is an invalid column name, why?

`SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: A.b_MANDT: line 1 col 43 (at pos 42)`

Original SQL Statement:

```
SELECT a."MANDT", a."VBELN", a."POSNR", a."b_MANDT" a_b_MANDT, a."b_VBELN" a_b_VBELN, a."VPOSN" a_VPOSN, b."MANDT" b_MANDT, b."VBELN" b_VBELN, b."VPOSN"
FROM (
    SELECT a."MANDT", a."VBELN", a."POSNR", b."MANDT" b_MANDT, b."VBELN" b_VBELN, b."VPOSN"
    FROM "SAP_ECC".VBAP a
    LEFT JOIN "SAP_ECC".VEDA b ON a.MANDT = b.MANDT AND a.VBELN = b.VBELN AND a.POSNR = b.VPOSN
) a
LEFT JOIN "SAP_ECC".VEDA b ON a.MANDT = b.MANDT AND a.VBELN = b.VBELN AND a.VPOSN = b.VPOSN
```

Comment: It would be kind to us if you reproduce your error on a much simpler structure and query that is more readable than your current query.  I mean, when the error message points to an error that is located in column 2635!!, then it's a bit much.

Comment: @sstan, Thanks for the feedback, I have deleted unnecessary columns :)

Comment: I must be missing something of why you are selecting a LEFT JOIN of essentially the same LEFT JOIN on the interior select statemtent instead of just writing a query but perhaps that is part of the simplification.  And just and a suggestion don't reuse table aliases in the same query.

Comment: The reason is very unspectacular. It's just because it's defined like this in a view. And in this view the join condition is slightly different. I'm not sure if it's useful as well. And yeah, I would not use the same aliases in the same query. But because I automatically generate this statement I am very sure that there won't go something wrong because of that.

Comment: what usually goes wrong about re-using table aliases in the same query is people get confused as far as which columns they can access/use via the queries plus when someone else goes to look at and debug your code it make it less readable.  But to each their own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing  `b."MANDT" b_MANDT` to  `b."MANDT" "b_MANDT"`.
Not sure what DB you are using, but typically, unless quoted, the alias defaults to upper-case yet you are trying to reference it as mixed-case.